# Correct formatting for docker-compose environment variables that are command line arguments

Tags: bash, docker-compose, yaml

I have the following docker-compose service:

```
  maxwell:
    image: zendesk/maxwell:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      # <irrelevant config here>
      MAXWELL_PRODUCER: stdout
      MAXWELL_OPTIONS: >-
        # <irrelevant config here>
        --filter="exclude:*.*"
```

The file running inside the image starts the server like this:

```sh
exec `dirname $0`/maxwell  --user=$MYSQL_USERNAME --password=$MYSQL_PASSWORD --host=$MYSQL_HOST --producer=$MAXWELL_PRODUCER $MAXWELL_OPTIONS
```

The server this image runs, Maxwell, is not starting because it's complaining about malformed options. However, if I SSH into the image (with `docker-compose run maxwell bash`), and input the above filter option, exactly as written, the server starts normally.

I tried parsing the above YAML and looking at the string. It looks correct, so I don't think it's a YAML formatting issue.

What could be causing the command line option to get mangled?

Comment: As you've shown it, `# ........` is the culprit as it is parsed as content (not comment) inside a block scalar. However, I assume that you meant to strip irrelevant content.

Comment: Yeah sorry I should have made that clear. You’re right that’s not a good comment, but there’s a lot of irrelevant config in there